# Convert class 'method' into list in Python

Tags: python, converters

I wanna convert text of BeautifulSoup into list. I did like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
story = soup.find("div", attrs={'class': "expandbook__resume"})
story = story.get_text
story = list(story)
```

But it says "TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable"

Comment: get_text is a method, so just call it to get the result: `story = story.get_text()`

Comment: I wanted to replace specific word from that, like this: story = story.replace("Plus", "")

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)
There it states **get_text** is a method and should be called (**get_text()**).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
story = soup.find("div", attrs={'class': "expandbook__resume"})
story = story.get_text()
story = list(story)
```